# How to fix my navigation bar to the top of the page

Tags: css, layout, css-position

I was wondering if anyone could help me out fix my the top portion of my webpage to stay.

I have tried using the position:fixed attribute, but this hinders everything as then my content overlaps the fixed divs.

My website is here:

[www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html](http://www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html)

I would like everything above the navbar, navbar included to stay glued to the top of the page and the content to scroll under it.

I realise this may mean i'll have to change the majority of my images to jpg instead of png. However, i was wondering if there was anyway around this? As in create a false line that the content scrolls under, then disappears, rather than reaching the top of the page, by where you will see it through the transparent parts of the PNG images. I don't want to use an iframe, really, unless this is the only way.

Thanks!

Comment: The code should not be on an external site, the code should be here. If you also need to include screenshots, do so; but just linking to a third party site makes it so we never have a 'point in time' view of the code, which is essential for finding and fixing problems for future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `iframe` is certainly not the right choice here. Put a div around the stuff you want to have on top, put `position: fixed` on it and position it to the top left corner.

```
<div class="ontop">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="contact"></div>
    <div id="navbar"></div>
</div>
```

After that, add some `margin-top` on `#content-holder` that equals to the height of `.ontop`. This is necessary because it is taken out of the document flow (because of `position: fixed`) and content will go under it.

If you also add `background-color: white` to `.ontop`, your transparency problems will be gone.

Tried to replicate your setup, here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/jXJMx/).

Comment: +1 The important part is the margin-top for the other content

Comment: Problem with this, is the content scrolls 'over' my navigation bar, and even if i added CSS to make sure it went under, you would still see the content through PNG transparent images as it scrolls up..

I need a stop where the text vanishes under.

Comment: @CrookedCartoon Put a `background-color: white` on the `.ontop` div :). And remove default `margin` on `body`.

Comment: @CrookedCartoon Adding `z-index: 10` on `.ontop` helps.

Comment: Adding the z-index works a treat: http://www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html
However, is there anyway to keep the transparency of the curves? Since i set the background of the 'ontop' div to white, there is now a straight edge to where the content scrolls under. Can avoid this?

Comment: @CrookedCartoon Well, instead of setting the background on ontop, you could set it on top, logo and contact separately, but not on navbar. And rework the image a bit to be transparent only when it is needed (not on the top).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, this is what i have done:

www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html

Answer (score -1):

you may try this

please update below css as i have updated the image by making the portion at the bottom transparent,making the top background white. [1 - DOWNLOAD IMAGE AND CHECK IT]

```
#ontop {
    background: inherit;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
#contact {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 1127px;
}
#logo {
    height: 62px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1127px;
    z-index: 1111;
}
```

]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8xQX.png)

Comment: So what way is this different from my solution? :) You could have at least taken the time to change `ontop` to something else :).

Comment: without background top fixed is not working proper, so it is working properly if you can try this.

Comment: Again;

http://www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html

Works great, however, how do i maintain the transparency of the curves so the content doesn't hit a straight 'white' line?

Comment: answer wil update please now try this